# Constructing possibilities of a generating function

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, recursion

I want to find all the possible ways that 4 variables can be summed to a given number. Suppose I have the variables
$$x=x_0+x_1+x_2+x_3$$
I want to fill $x_0,x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ such that $x_0$ and $x_3$ can be zero or 1 and $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be equal or between 0 to 3. For example if I ask $x=3$ there will be following possibilities: 
$$1+1+1+0$$
$$1+1+0+1$$
$$1+0+1+1$$
$$0+1+1+1$$
$$1+2+0+0$$
$$1+0+2+0$$
$$0+2+0+1$$
$$0+0+2+1$$
$$0+2+1+0$$
$$0+1+2+0$$
$$0+3+0+0$$
$$0+0+3+0$$
How can I generate these possibilities in Mathematica. Also what if I have more variables for example: $x_0+x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$ and so on?

Update: In fact this problem is coming from the following generating function:
$$1 + 4 x + 8 x^2 + 12 x^3 + 14 x^4 + 12 x^5 + 8 x^6 + 4 x^7 + x^8$$
the coefficients are the possible ways of forming the sum. For instance if we want to make the sum to be equal to 3 then there are 12 possible ways of assigning numbers and so on and so forth. Thus it is important to have that $x_0$ and $x_4$ must be 0 or 1, and $x_2$ and $x_3$ must strictly be between zero and 3. So for instance to make the sum equal to 5 one can not have 0+5+0+0 as it is not allowed.

Comment: Could do: `In[23]:= Sum[x0^j, {j, 0, 1}]*Sum[x1^j, {j, 0, 3}]*
 Sum[x2^j, {j, 0, 3}]*Sum[x3^j, {j, 0, 1}]

Out[23]= (1 + x0) (1 + x1 + x1^2 + x1^3) (1 + x2 + x2^2 + x2^3) (1 + 
   x3)` Not too hard to automate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 2:** You can also use [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) as follows:

```
Flatten@Array[If[Plus[##] == 3, HoldForm[Plus[##]], ## &[]] &, {2, 4, 4, 2}, 0]
```

> {0+0+2+1, 0+0+3+0, 0+1+1+1, 0+1+2+0, 0+2+0+1, 0+2+1+0, 0+3+0+0, 1+0+1+1, 1+0+2+0, 1+1+0+1, 1+1+1+0, 1+2+0+0}

**Update:** You can use [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html):

```
n = 4;
t = 3;
v = Array[x, n, 0];
eqn = Total[v] == t;
constraints = And[0 <= v[[1]] <= 1, 0 <= v[[2]]<=3, 0 <= v[[3]] <= 3,  0 <= v[[4]] <= 1];
v /. Solve[{eqn, constraints}, v, Integers]
```

> {{0, 0, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 
>     1}, {0, 2, 1, 0}, {0, 3, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 
>     0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 0}}

```
Inactive[Plus] @@@ soln // Column
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) or [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) as follows:

```
l0 = l3 = Range[0, 1]; 
l1 = l2 = Range[0, 3];

res1 = Flatten@Outer[Inactive[Plus], l0, l1, l2, l3];
res2 = Tuples[Inactive[Plus][l0, l1, l2, l3]];

res1 == res2
```

> True

```
Select[res1, Activate[#]==3&] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I think he meant you need also `Select[Tuples[...], Total[#] == 3 &]` for his case :-)

Comment: Thank you @Vitaliy. Missed that part:)

Comment: @kglr Thanks for this but I wanted the first and last integers to be strictly 1 and 0.

Comment: @William, missed that part too:) Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks @kglr it also as an additional constrain. x_2 and x_3 can shall be between  0 to 3. So this would break the code for higher t. Same problem as bob's code. for instance it you put t=5 you must only have 12 output, but you get 20, because you have elements like {0, 0, 4, 1}, {0, 0, 5, 0} and so on.

Comment: I can tell you the generating function: 1 + 4 x + 8 x^2 + 12 x^3 + 14 x^4 + 12 x^5 + 8 x^6 + 4 x^7 + x^8 so one must have 1 element that the sum is zero, 4 elements that the sum is equal to 1, and so on. In case of x=3 we have 12 elements (possibilities)

Comment: William, fixed that too.

Answer (score 4):

```
partition[total_, nVar_] := 
 Flatten[Permutations /@ (PadRight[#, nVar] & /@ 
     IntegerPartitions[total]), 1]

part = Select[
  partition[3, 
   4], (#[[1]] == 0 || #[[1]] == 1) && (#[[4]] == 0 || #[[4]] == 1) &]

(* {{0, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 1, 
  0}, {0, 2, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 
  0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1}} *)

Column[StringJoin /@ (Riffle[#, "+"] & /@ part /. 
    n_Integer :> ToString[n])]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Corrected definition of `partition` to cover cases when `total > nVar`

```
partition[total_, nVar_] := 
 Select[Flatten[
   Permutations /@ (PadRight[#, nVar] & /@ IntegerPartitions[total]), 1], 
  Total[#] == total &]

part = Select[
  partition[5, 
   4], (#[[1]] == 0 || #[[1]] == 1) && (#[[4]] == 0 || #[[4]] == 1) && 
    Max[#] <= 3 &]

(* {{0, 3, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 3, 0}, {1, 3, 1, 0}, {1, 3, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 
  3, 1}, {0, 3, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 
  1}, {1, 1, 2, 1}} *)
```

Comment: @kglr - Thanks, corrected error

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is almost what I am looking for, just a further question, if I write: part = Select[
  partition[5, 
   4], (#[[1]] == 0 || #[[1]] == 1) && (#[[4]] == 0 || #[[4]] == 1) &] I get the following list: {{0, 5, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5, 0}, {1, 4, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 4, 0}, {0, 4, 1, 
  0}, {0, 4, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 4, 1}, {0, 3, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 
  3, 0}, {1, 3, 1, 0}, {1, 3, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 3, 1}, {0, 
  3, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 
  1}, {1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}} where the first 8 elements are redundant.

Comment: as x_2, and x_3 shall be between 0 to 3 only. How can I fix this?

Comment: also in this case that I specified, there is a term {1,1,1,1} that is not giving the sum equal to 5 and thus the codes breaks at higher orders.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation of my answer to the linked question that is much faster than the accepted answer here:

```
tups[n_, k_] := With[{tuples = Tuples[Join[{Range[2]},ConstantArray[Range[n+1],n-1],{Range[2]}]-1]},
    Pick[tuples, Total[tuples, {2}], k]
]
```

Check:

```
tups[3,3]
```

> {{0, 0, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 
>     1, 0}, {0, 3, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 
>     0}, {1, 2, 0, 0}}

Comparison:

```
r1 = tups[6, 4]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Flatten@Array[If[Plus[##] == 4, HoldForm[Plus[##]], ## &[]] &, {2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2}, 0]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === Replace[r2, HoldForm[Plus[x__]] -> {x}, {1}]
```

> {0.002733, Null}
>
> {0.159457, Null}
>
> True