# Generalisation of a generating function

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

I have asked a question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182247/constructing-possibilities-of-a-generating-function).
I want to reproduce the coefficients of a generating function of the form: 
$$(1 + x)^2 (1 + x + x^2 + x^3+\cdots+x^n)^{n-1}$$
It is important that $x_0$ and $x_n$ to be strictly 0 or 1 and $x_1$ to $x_2$ can be any number within 0 and n (nothing higher). Here are two examples: 
For $n=3$ we have:

```
In: (1 + x)^2 (1 + x + x^2 + x^3)^2 // Expand
Out: 1 + 4 x + 8 x^2 + 12 x^3 + 14 x^4 + 12 x^5 + 8 x^6 + 4 x^7 + x^8
```

We can produce the coefficients as:

```
n = 3;
m = n + 1;
tabel = Table[
v = Array[x, m, 0];
eqn = Total[v] == t;
constraints = 
And[0 <= v[[1]] <= 1, 0 <= v[[2]] <= n, 0 <= v[[3]] <= n, 
 0 <= v[[4]] <= 1];
v /. Solve[{eqn, constraints}, v, Integers], {t, 0, 8}];
Table[Length[tabel[[i]]], {i, Length[tabel]}]
```

which gives:

```
{1, 4, 8, 12, 14, 12, 8, 4, 1}
```

as desired. For $n=4$ one had to add extra constraint and change the $t$ range. 
We have:

```
In: (1 + x)^2 (1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)^3 // Expand
Out: 1 + 5 x + 13 x^2 + 25 x^3 + 41 x^4 + 58 x^5 + 70 x^6 + 74 x^7 + 
70 x^8 + 58 x^9 + 41 x^10 + 25 x^11 + 13 x^12 + 5 x^13 + x^14
```

thus $t$ should be from 0 to 14, 
 so we have:

```
n = 4;
m = n + 1;
tabel = Table[
v = Array[x, m, 0];
eqn = Total[v] == t;
constraints = 
And[0 <= v[[1]] <= 1, 0 <= v[[2]] <= n, 0 <= v[[3]] <= n, 
 0 <= v[[4]] <= n, 0 <= v[[5]] <= 1];
v /. Solve[{eqn, constraints}, v, Integers], {t, 0, 14}];
Table[Length[tabel[[i]]], {i, Length[tabel]}]
```

I wonder if these modifications can be done automatically so that one doesn't have to add a constraint by hand and change the range.

**Note: I want the output `table` to be in a format so that I can see all of the possibilities of the sums.** 
For instance, for n=3, `table[[2]]` should give all of the possibilities such that the total is equal to 1.

```
{{0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

An even faster method (I also modified the order of each possibility as requested in the comments):

```
tups[n_] := Values @ GroupBy[
    Tuples[Join[{Range[2]}, ConstantArray[Range[n+1], n-1], {Range[2]}] - 1],
    Total
]
```

A comparison with the accepted answer:

```
r1 = tups[3]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = gen[3]; //AbsoluteTiming

Sort /@ r1 === Sort /@ Reverse @ r2[[All, 2]]
```

> {0.000123, Null}
>
> {0.001075, Null}
>
> True

Almost an order of magnitude faster for $n=3$. For $n=7$:

```
r1 = tups[7]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = gen[7]; //AbsoluteTiming

Sort /@ r1 === Sort /@ Reverse @ r2[[All, 2]]
```

> {0.195056, Null}
>
> {29.7257, Null}
>
> True

**Original method**

Here's a modification of @kglr's answer to your linked question:

```
sums[n_]:= Last @ Reap[
    Array[Sow[{##}, Plus[##]]&, Join[{2}, ConstantArray[n+1, n-1], {2}], 0],
    _,
    #2&
]
```

For $n=3$:

```
sums[3][[2]]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}

And a couple checks:

```
Length /@ sums[3]
Length /@ sums[4]
```

> {1, 4, 8, 12, 14, 12, 8, 4, 1}
>
> {1, 5, 13, 25, 41, 58, 70, 74, 70, 58, 41, 25, 13, 5, 1}

Comment: Thanks Carl, while it produces the correct answer, I need the elements to be in right place, as I will use them later as a list for other computation, If you try sums[3][[3]] you'd see the first element is not right, {0, 0, 0, 2} the first and last element of this must be 0 or 1, so the only way to assign 2 is {0, 2, 0, 0} and {0,0,2,0} to produce the sum of 2 without violating the constraints. This was happening at kglr's answer.

Comment: @William I modified the code as requested. Note that my answer is over an order of magnitude faster than the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, this is much nicer for the task at hand (and I for one upvoted).

Comment: @CarlWoll & Daniel I have changed my acceptation. due to timing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

One can automate the generating construction readily enough using `Product` and `Sum`. Getting total degrees and then the subsets of balues that give them is a bit more work. I show one method below.

```
gen[n_] := Module[
  {vars, x, t, genFunc, coeffs},
  vars = Array[x, n + 1, 0];
  genFunc = (1 + First[vars])*(1 + Last[vars])*
     Product[Sum[vars[[j]]^k, {k, 0, n}], {j, 2, n}] /. 
    Thread[vars -> t*vars];
  coeffs = GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[genFunc, t][[1]];
  Map[{#[[1, 1]], 
     GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[#[[2]], vars][[1, All, 1]]} &,
    coeffs]
  ]
```

Example:

```
gen[3]

(* Out[59]= {{8, {{1, 3, 3, 1}}}, {7, {{1, 3, 3, 0}, {1, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2,
     3, 1}, {0, 3, 3, 1}}}, {6, {{1, 3, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3,
     0}, {1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {0, 3, 3, 0}, {0, 3, 2, 1}, {0, 
    2, 3, 1}}}, {5, {{1, 3, 1, 0}, {1, 3, 0, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 
    1, 1}, {1, 1, 3, 0}, {1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 0, 3, 1}, {0, 3, 2, 0}, {0,
     3, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 3, 0}, {0, 2, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 3, 1}}}, {4, {{1, 3,
     0, 0}, {1, 2, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 
    1}, {1, 0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 1}, {0, 3, 1, 0}, {0, 3, 0, 1}, {0, 2,
     2, 0}, {0, 2, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 3, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 3, 
    1}}}, {3, {{1, 2, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 2, 
    0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 1}, {0, 1,
     2, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 1}}}, {2, {{1, 1, 0,
     0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 
    1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}}}, {1, {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 
    0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}}, {0, {{0, 0, 0, 0}}}} *)
```

Looks spiffier if one uses `TableForm` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I didn't understand your question, but

```
Table[ CoefficientList[(1 + x)^2 (Sum[x^i, {i, 0, n}])^(n - 1),x] , {n, 1, 5}]
```

evaluates the list of coefficients  you're looking for.

Comment: Yes this is wrong. As I said I need to know the possible sum. The table there gives me all the possible sums but yours does not.